# How can I print this to file in bash?

Tags: bash, files, find

I have no idea what I should do to make it work:

```bsh
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '\t%s\t%f\n' |sort -n -r | > txt.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '\t%s\t%f\n' | sort -n -r > txt.txt
```

You have to remove the `|` at the end, `>` means redirect the `stdout`(standard output) to a file.

If there is an error that text will be displayed in the `stderr`. Which is the standard output for all errors.

If you want to redirect that to a file: `2> /path/to/a/file`

Due note that there is a difference between `>` and `>>`.

- `>` Will overwrite the entire file's content
- `>>` Will append at the end of the file's content